# Cannot work my element visible in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing a selenium script using java.

In my scenario, I have a select button and a OK button. Select button is enabled and OK button is disabled when I first loaded the page. When I click on select button, a pop-up window appears.

Then I select a date from a date picker in the pop-up window. After selecting the date I click confirm button in the pop-up window. After click on confirm button the pop-up window closes and Book Now button enables.

This is my test scenario. But, when I run this my test fails at the point of clicking the Book Now button.

So, I used `FluentWait` to recover this. But, when I'm running my code it just ignores the FluentWait part and run the code.

Can anyone tell me how to click OK button using my script.

Here is my code.

```
// Select Days
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='myModal0']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]/a")).click(); 
System.out.println("User Selected the days the service is offered");

Thread.sleep(4000);

// Click Confirm Button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='myModal0']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/button")).click(); 
System.out.println("User clicked Confirm Button");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Click Book Now Button
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='0']/td[6]/button")).click();
//System.out.println("User Clicked Book Now Button");   


System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaa");

class CheckForFoo implements Function<WebDriver,WebElement> {
    @override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
          return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='0']/td[6]/button"));
    }
}

FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)    
     .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)    
     .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)   
     .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = (WebElement) wait.until(new CheckForFoo());

System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbb");
```

Thanks in advance. :)

- edit -

Before I used FluentWait I got the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (1460.7666015625, 159.03334045410156). Other element would receive the click: 
>   Command duration or timeout: 84 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'ET_LAHIRU', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: 16e51961-3d8c-4c31-9dec-547d04235eac
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
>       at selrcdemo.Activities.activities(Activities.java:97)
>       at selrcdemo.ayubomain.main(ayubomain.java:69)

But, after adding FluentWait no errors. But, it doesn't do what I want. :)

Comment: plz post your error as well

Comment: Added. Please look at it. :)

Comment: looks like issue not related to wait. first move to element then click.

Comment: @murali seleniumtrainer and how am I suppose to do that? tried several things. but no luck. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as per the exception please first do some wait before clicking on the Book Now Button like

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

it will work,

and also as per error there is no need to use fluent wait cause what fluent wait does is it looks for the element in the DOM and the moment it finds it ,it allows next action to begin, this is why when you have applied fluent wait it did nothing cause element was available in the DOM,

but if you want to understand the error then it clearly says **Element is not clickable at point (1460.7666015625, 159.03334045410156)** which means element is present inside the DOM but not got a fixed position hence it requires some extra time to get fixed position hence use (Thread.sleep(5000);)

Hope this helps you